# Form that submits multiple fields with same attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a pretty typical controller with a `new` action. It looks like this:

```
  def new
    @child = Child.new
  end
```

The form fields in my view is also fairly simple. They looks like:

```
<%= form.text_field :name, placeholder: "John" %>
<%= form.text_field :birthday, placeholder: "MM/DD/YYYY" %>
```

I'd like my view to submit multiple `children` in this form. I'll have javascript create them dynamically.

How do I deal with this in the `new` and action in my controller? And how do I deal with this in my view?

It seems like must be a way to submit an array of `children`. I feel confident that I can deal with the array in a `create` controller action, but I'm not sure where to start here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use nested_attributes.

Look if this could help.

[Cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon)